# Wieferich primes and arithmetic prgressions

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic-progression, congruences

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Let $K$ be a number field with Galois group $G$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ stable under conjugation. Then the Cebotarev density theorem gives that $$\mathcal{L}=\{\ell : Frob_{\ell}\in H\}$$ has positive density. Let $M$ be a large positive integer and let $\mathcal{D}=\{t_1;...;t_s\}$ be the set of all positive square free integers less then $M$.
Is it there a prime number $\ell\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $$\ell=tx^2+q^2,$$ where $t\in\mathcal{D}$ and $p$ is a non-Wieferich prime of basis $q$, i.e., $q^{p-1}\not\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$ ?
Or a prime $\ell\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $$\ell=tx^2+q^{2k},$$ where $t\in\mathcal{D}$ and $p$ is a non-Wieferich prime of basis $q$, i.e., $q^{p-1}\not\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$ and $q^{k}\not\equiv1\pmod{p}$ ?